# How can I open an URL using PyQt when clicking on a button?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I want to open an URL when someone click a button using PyQt4.
I used some suggested code already but none of them worked for me.

```
btn.clicked.connect(webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com'))
```

Comment: Please, give example what you use and why it's not worked for you

Comment: I put the example up there

Comment: And what is the type of webbrowser?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just need the code that can sole my problem.

Comment: Use a lambda, define a new function or use `functools.partial` to create a function with no arguments to pass to connect. You should not have the () at the end. You are passing the function itself and not its return value.

Comment: @Trilarion [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) is a standard module.

Comment: I'm sorry, But I don't seems to be understanding what are you trying to say, Because I'm just a beginner
could you please  make it more clearly?

Comment: This question should not be closed as too broad (it may have been in the beginning but not anymore). It is now very localized. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Paul Ronney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198904/how-can-i-open-an-url-using-pyqt/34200202#comment56144452_34198904) pointed out:
In your code you call the `open` method of object `webbrowser` immediately at the time this line of code is parsed. That is not what you want, you want to execute it later, when the button is clicked. For that you need to specify a method without executing it, i.e. without the `()`.

The method way:

```
def open_webbrowser():
    webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com')

btn.clicked.connect(open_webbrowser)
```

Or with lambda expression:

```
btn.clicked.connect(lambda: webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It worked

Comment: @Justastudent You're welcome. Credit goes to Paul Ronney as well. If it solved your problem and if you like that, do you know that you can upvote answers (clicking on arrow up) and also mark them as solved (the question), with clicking on the question mark next to the score.